# Using Java in javascript fails in IE

Tags: java, javascript, internet-explorer

I am tring to use java.lang.String inside my javascript file. But this fails in IE.

Is there a workaround for IE.

This is what I'm trying to do.

```
var byteArray = (new java.lang.String("asdf")).getBytes();
```

Comment: I don't understand? You are aware that Java and JavaScript have nothing directly to do with each other? Are you looking for a JS alternative to this?

Comment: why the hell are you using java inside of javascript ? oO

Comment: Might want to read this... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javascript

Comment: That code works perfectly fine in firefox. IE creates some problem. I know Java and js are different. That doesnt prevent anyone from using java in js...

Comment: Actually people you can code Java in JavaScript. http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/jscript/ch22_03.htm Would I be caught doing this insane stuff? Nope. lol

Comment: More info on it: http://books.google.com/books?id=2weL0iAfrEMC&lpg=PT602&ots=_82yoA-ZcH&pg=PT598#v=onepage&q&f=false

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unlike Firefox, Internet Explorer cannot interact with Java.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike Firefox; IE doesn't have direct access to the Java libraries and it would be somewhat insane to 1.) assume Java is installed 2.) use the Java libraries within client side script.